# setting variable to an attribute in class gives me an id instead of string

Tags: ruby

i have a problem where i try to get an attribute from a class that is suppose to be a string. However it gives me the id of the object instead

```
# tenant can be a string or a Tenant Object
def return_name (tenant)
  if tenant.class == "Tenant"
    name = tenant.name
  else
    name = tenant
  end
  return name
end

# puts return_name (tenantObj) will print out
<Tenant:0x007fc9ba1fe3a8>

# puts return_name ("denis") will print out
denis
```

how do you solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    def return_name (tenant)
      tenant.is_a?(Tenant) ? tenant.name : tenant
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

`#class` in ruby returns class, but not as string.

```
def return_name (tenant)
  if tenant.class == Tenant # or tenant.instance_of? Tenant
    tenant.name
  else
    tenant
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to extend Harunojikan answer;

```
def return_name (tenant)
  tenant.respond_to? :name ? tenant.name : tenant
end
```

I think respond_to is more idiomatic in ruby